# Drag object locked at certain distance/radius from camera view

Tags: javascript, 3d, three.js

[image]

I have a camera in the center of the scene, 1 sphere at z=400 distance from the camera, with it's parent in the center.

I want to drag the sphere up/down/left/right from the view but at the same time not change it's z - position from the center.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using another sphere and make it invisible, add `side: THREE.DoubleSide` to the material and use it for raycasting.