# Three.js drag controls fix distance from camera

Tags: javascript, three.js

I'm using [Three.DragControls](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/master/examples/js/controls/DragControls.js) to drag an object around a scene. As the object gets dragged it's distance from camera seems to be getting further away.

My question is similar to this unanswered one [Drag object locked at certain distance/radius from camera view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19364909/drag-object-locked-at-certain-distance-radius-from-camera-view)

Is there a clever way to fix that _intersection.sub( _offset ) a certain distance from the camera in the centre of the scene?

I've added a sphere to the scene

```
    dragSphere = new THREE.Mesh(new THREE.SphereGeometry(200, 60, 40 ),new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial());
    dragSphere.name = "dragSphere";
    dragSphere.visible = false;
    dragSphere.scale.x = -1;
    scene.add(dragSphere);
```

Somewhere in here

```
  function onDocumentMouseMove( event ) {

    event.preventDefault();

    var offset = $("#container").offset();
    var rect = _domElement.getBoundingClientRect();
    _mouse.x = ( ( event.clientX - rect.left - (offset.left/2) ) / ( rect.width - rect.left ) ) * 2 - 1;
    _mouse.y = - ( ( event.clientY - rect.top ) / ( rect.bottom - rect.top) ) * 2 + 1;

    _raycaster.setFromCamera( _mouse, _camera );

    if ( _selected && scope.enabled ) {

        if ( _raycaster.ray.intersectPlane( _plane, _intersection ) ) {

            if(_right){

                _deltaX = event.x - _startPoint.x;
                _deltaY = event.y - _startPoint.y;

                _selected.rotation.y += (_deltaX/50);
                _selected.rotation.x += (_deltaY/50);

                console.log(_selected.position);

                _startPoint.x = event.x;
                _startPoint.y = event.y;

                _lastMoveTimestamp = new Date();
            }
            else{
                _selected.position.copy( _intersection.sub( _offset ) );
                _selected.lookAt(camera.position);
            }

        }

        scope.dispatchEvent( { type: 'drag', object: _selected } );

        return;

    }

    _raycaster.setFromCamera( _mouse, _camera );

    var intersects = _raycaster.intersectObjects( _objects , true  );

    if ( intersects.length > 0 ) {

        var object = intersects[ 0 ].object;

        if(object.type === "Mesh")
            if(object.parent)
                if(object.parent.type == "Object3D")
                    object = object.parent;

        _plane.setFromNormalAndCoplanarPoint( _camera.getWorldDirection( _plane.normal ), object.position );

        if ( _hovered !== object ) {

            scope.dispatchEvent( { type: 'hoveron', object: object } );

            _domElement.style.cursor = 'pointer';
            _hovered = object;

        }

    } else {

        if ( _hovered !== null ) {

            scope.dispatchEvent( { type: 'hoveroff', object: _hovered } );

            _domElement.style.cursor = 'auto';
            _hovered = null;

        }

    }

}

function onDocumentMouseDown( event ) {

    event.preventDefault();

    _right = event.which == 3 || event.button == 2;

    _raycaster.setFromCamera( _mouse, _camera );

    var intersects = _raycaster.intersectObjects( _objects , true );

    if ( intersects.length > 0 ) {

        _selected = intersects[ 0 ].object;

       if(_selected.type == "Mesh" && _selected.parent.type == "Object3D")
         _selected = _selected.parent;

        if ( _raycaster.ray.intersectPlane( _plane, _intersection ) ) {

            if(_right){
                _mouseDown = true;

                _startPoint = {
                    x: event.clientX,
                    y: event.clientY
                };

                _rotateStartPoint = _rotateEndPoint = projectOnTrackball(0, 0);
            }
            else
                _offset.copy( _intersection ).sub( _selected.position );
        }

        _domElement.style.cursor = 'move';

        scope.dispatchEvent( { type: 'dragstart', object: _selected } );

    }
    else
        scope.dispatchEvent( { type: 'nodrag' } );


}
```

In the part that does the dragging, i.e.

```
if ( _raycaster.ray.intersectPlane( _plane, _intersection ) ) {
    _selected.position.copy( _intersection.sub( _offset ) );
    _selected.lookAt(camera.position);
}
```

I need to get it to use the Sphere intersection to apply the position so it drags along the surface of the sphere.

Answer (score 3):

This might not be a full answer, but could get you pointed in the right direction since I am in a similar situation where I was trying to get objects to drag along a plane. I created my own modified version of the DragControls.js function to support passing in a plane as a parameter (renaming it to DragControlsPlane.js first), like so:

```
THREE.DragControlsPlane = function (_objects, _camera, _domElement, _plane)
```

Thats at the top of the original DragControls.js. Then comment out the line that initializes the _plane var:

```
//var _plane = new THREE.Plane();
```

Then you'll need to comment out the line that shifts the plane to the camera's view (about midway down):

```
//_plane.setFromNormalAndCoplanarPoint(_camera.getWorldDirection(_plane.normal), object.position);
```

Then at the bottom rename these to line up with your new function name:

```
THREE.DragControlsPlane.prototype = Object.create(THREE.EventDispatcher.prototype);
THREE.DragControlsPlane.prototype.constructor = THREE.DragControlsPlane;
```

And then use the new function in your scripts. The rest of the DragControls already does the rest, but you might need to modify it a little more to work with a sphere. This is working for me, at least for a plane surface. Maybe mr. doob can add this as an actual feature soon, *wink* *wink*. Let me know if you get it working for a sphere! I don't expect an upvote on this as it's not the full answer, but hopefully it will help someone out there!